# Bitwise operators versus .NET abstractions for bit manipulation in C# prespective

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to get basic skills in working with bits using C#.NET. I posted an example yesterday with a simple problem that needs bit manipulation which led me to the fact that there are two main approaches - using `bitwise operators` or using .NET abstractions such as `BitArray` (Please let me know if there are more build-in tools for working with bits other than `BitArray` in .NET and how to find more info for them if there are?).

I understand that `bitwise operators` work faster but using `BitArray` is something much more easier for me, but one thing I really try to avoid is learning bad practices. Even though my personal preferences are for the .NET abstraction(s) I want to know which i actually better to learn and use in a real program. Thinking about it I'm tempted to think that .NET abstractions are not that bad at, after all there must be reason to be there and maybe being a beginner it's more natural to learn the abstraction and later on improve my skills with low level operations, but this is just random thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on what you are doing with it. I'd say use bitwise operations when speed is more of a concern as they have much less overhead. Otherwise, BitArray's should be fine. The main overhead associated is function calls and some limits on "tricks" you can do.

For instance, if you wanted to do something if bits 0, 3, or 4 where set in a value:

```
if((value & 0b11001)>0) //not sure this is valid syntax, but you get the idea
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Which because integers are a native CLR type, translates almost directly to just 3 native opcodes, `mov`, `and`, and `cmp`

where as for a BitArray, the most effecient way I see is this:

```
if(value[0] || value[3] || value[4])
{
  //...
}
```

Where (assuming not JIT), this equals up to 3 function calls of light complexity. The simplest way to get a bit value from the backing integer(I assume) of a BitArray looks like this:

```
bool GetBit(int which)
{
  return value & (1 << which)>0;
}
```

This basically means it equates to being about 2 times slower *for just one bit* For this super simple case, this would mean about 6 times slower since we are checking 3 bits.

And also for BitArrays, copies may be more expensive, as they aren't a native CLR type. I'd suspect this overhead is JITed away for the most part, but still something to consider, especially if targetting a compact framework.

Basically, only use BitArrays if you're not ever going to need to do complex bitwise operations on them.

Note: you can also use a hybrid approach of converting between integers and BitArrays, but this can have quite a bit of overhead as well.

Comment: The `cmp` could be deleted because `and` sets the flags anyway, and then the `mov` can be deleted by changing the `and` to `test`, which is nondestructive. So it's only one instruction really. (in theory, anyway. is the JIT compiler smart enough?)

Comment: Well, it depends. @harold. It's a complete guess as it's up to the JIT compiler anyway. With the way the IL works, it's a series of push, and, compare, branch-if-true, etc. so that's mainly what I was going off of. I'm sure someone really dedicated could see what the JIT compiler natively compiles this too

Comment: Well I tested it, and the JIT compiler turns out to be smart enough to generate just the `test` instruction. At least the version I tested it on, which is version 4.

Comment: Shouldn't `GetBit` look more like `(backing_array[which >> 5] & (1u << which)) != 0`, by the way? It has to be an array, right?

Comment: @harold yes. I was just simplifying it. I'd assume it works behind the scenes by having an array of either bytes or integers

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know which i actually better to learn and use in a real program.

Learn 'em both. They are not that hard to understand and you could imagine scenarios where one would be better than the other.

Although I agree with @Marc Gravell above, I'd only think about using a BitArray if I have a huge number of bits I need to deal with (and speed isn't too much of an issue), but if you end up in that situation, you might be doing something wrong anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Keep this in mind at all times when programming:

> "There is no problem that cannot be solved by adding another layer of indirection, *except* for the problem of having too many layers of indirection". - *David Wheeler (para.)*

By using BitArray, you add a layer of indirection, which abstracts away the details of how bits are managed and the value of each bit is produced and manipulated. This is usually a good thing and to be encouraged; it creates cleaner, more elegant, easier-to-read code.

However, what happens when you need to do something complex, which BitArray doesn't let you do (or makes extremely difficult to do)? At that point, your design is "overly abstract"; the levels of abstraction prevent you doing what you want to do because they "dumb it down" too much. That's a signal to refactor with fewer abstractions, in this case using bitwise operators which require more care and understanding but will basically do anything that's possible to do to a set of bits.

So in short, use the BitArray to solve your problem until using BitArray becomes its own problem. Don't worry about what you're going to do without BitArray; that can be worried about *if and when* that is ever necessary. Just don't forget how to use bitwise operators, or that they exist.

Comment: +1. Especially "don't forget how to use bitwise operators, or that they exist." :) I'd go slightly farther in "use the BitArray to solve your problem" - don't use bit operations/BitArray unless you know it is exactly what you need (i.e. you get bit flags from somewhere or you solving "how many 1 in binary representation of this value). In most of your code you'll never use either - regular `bool isReady` properties and fields are significantly easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Migrating Marc Gravel's response from a comment to an answer:</sup>

> [...] in virtually every common scenario I can think of, the operator approach would be preferred. The only time I'd look at BitArray is when I needed an **arbitrarily-large** set of flags, which a: is very rare, and b: is trivial to implement via a simple byte-array or int-array *anyway* –
> [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)  
> [Sep 13, 2012 at 15:41](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409830/bitwise-operators-versus-net-abstractions-for-bit-manipulation-in-c-sharp-presp#comment16678701_12409830)